# How to run (Google) benchmarks in ROS2

Tags: ros2, colcon, ament

There exists an [ament_cmake_google_benchmark](https://index.ros.org/p/ament_cmake_google_benchmark/) package that can help building Google Benchmark tests within ROS2, but I can't find a way to invoke those benchmarks from the command line, e.g. with `colcon`, without manually running them from the `build` directory.

`colcon test` runs only the tests, but skips the benchmarks.

The `ament_cmake_google_benchmark` package doc suggests there is a way to run the benchmarks automatically and parse the results. Anyone knows the correct way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you configure the package with CMake, it gives this advice:

```
-- Performance tests are disabled by default, so Google Benchmark tests will be skipped. To enable these tests, set the CMake variable 'AMENT_RUN_PERFORMANCE_TESTS'.
```

So you have to decide at configure time to enable the tests. Pass the flag like this:

```
colcon build --cmake-args "-D AMENT_RUN_PERFORMANCE_TESTS=1"
```

then test the package

```
$ colcon test 
...
    Start 1: filter_benchmark
1/1 Test #1: filter_benchmark .................   Passed    1.56 sec

100% tests passed, 0 tests failed out of 1

Label Time Summary:
google_benchmark    =   1.56 sec*proc (1 test)
performance         =   1.56 sec*proc (1 test)

Total Test time (real) =   1.56 sec
```

I still find it easier to execute the benchmark executable directly rather than via Colcon/Ctest, so I can easily pass cmdline args; e.g.:

```
 build/my_pkg/filter_benchmark --benchmark_repetitions=10
```